# hf-tikz and sphinx are not playing well together

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, tikz

I am trying to add some color to my matrices in sphinx. I was using [hf-tikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz?lang=en) for it before. However, when I add it to Sphinx, it renders it incorrectly.

The result that I am trying to get is

[image]

The result I am getting is

[image]

Here is the code that I have.

**main.rst**:

```latex
.. math::

    \left(\begin{array}{cc}
        \tikzmarkin[style red]{a}a\tikzmarkend{a}
      & \tikzmarkin[style green]{b}b\tikzmarkend{b} \\
        \tikzmarkin[style blue]{c}c\tikzmarkend{c}
      & \tikzmarkin[style orange]{d}d\tikzmarkend{d} \\
    \end{array}\right)
    \star
    \left(\begin{array}{cc}
        \tikzmarkin[style red]{w}w\tikzmarkend{w}
      & \tikzmarkin[style green]{x}x\tikzmarkend{x} \\
        \tikzmarkin[style blue]{y}y\tikzmarkend{y}
      & \tikzmarkin[style orange]{z}z\tikzmarkend{z} \\
    \end{array}\right)
    =
    \left(\begin{array}{cc}
        \tikzmarkin[hor=style red]{aw}{a\star w}\tikzmarkend{aw}
      & \tikzmarkin[hor=style green]{bx}b\star x\tikzmarkend{bx} \\
        \tikzmarkin[hor=style blue]{cy}c\star y\tikzmarkend{cy}
      & \tikzmarkin[hor=style orange]{dz}d\star z\tikzmarkend{dz} \\
    \end{array}\right)
```

**conf.py**

```py
extensions = [
  'sphinx.ext.imgmath',
]

# Math configurations (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69770/51173)
imgmath_image_format = 'svg'
imgmath_use_preview = True
imgmath_latex_preamble = r'''
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
  \colorlet{myred}{red!50!purple!30}
  \colorlet{mygreen}{green!50!lime!60}
  \colorlet{myblue}{blue!50!white!50}
  \colorlet{myorange}{orange!80!red!60}
  \colorlet{mycyan}{cyan!90!blue!60}
  \colorlet{mymagenta}{magenta!90!red!60}
  \tikzset{
    style red/.style={
      set fill color=myred,
      set border color=white,
    },
    style green/.style={
      set fill color=mygreen,
      set border color=white,
    },
    style blue/.style={
      set fill color=myblue,
      set border color=white,
    },
    style orange/.style={
      set fill color=myorange,
      set border color=white,
    },
    style cyan/.style={
      set fill color=mycyan,
      set border color=white,
    },
    style magenta/.style={
      set fill color=mymagenta,
      set border color=white,
    },
    %
    hor/.style={
      above left offset={-0.15,0.31},
      below right offset={0.15,-0.125},
      #1
    },
    ver/.style={
      above left offset={-0.1,0.3},
      below right offset={0.15,-0.15},
      #1
    }
  }
'''
```

**Makefile**

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
#

# You can set these variables from the command line, and also
# from the environment for the first two.
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = source
BUILDDIR      = build

# Put it first so that "make" without argument is like "make help".
help:
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M help "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)

.PHONY: help Makefile

# Catch-all target: route all unknown targets to Sphinx using the new
# "make mode" option.  $(O) is meant as a shortcut for $(SPHINXOPTS).
%: Makefile
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

**make.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd %~dp0

REM Command file for Sphinx documentation

if "%SPHINXBUILD%" == "" (
    set SPHINXBUILD=sphinx-build
)
set SOURCEDIR=source
set BUILDDIR=build

if "%1" == "" goto help

%SPHINXBUILD% >NUL 2>NUL
if errorlevel 9009 (
    echo.
    echo.The 'sphinx-build' command was not found. Make sure you have Sphinx
    echo.installed, then set the SPHINXBUILD environment variable to point
    echo.to the full path of the 'sphinx-build' executable. Alternatively you
    echo.may add the Sphinx directory to PATH.
    echo.
    echo.If you don't have Sphinx installed, grab it from
    echo.http://sphinx-doc.org/
    exit /b 1
)

%SPHINXBUILD% -M %1 %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%
goto end

:help
%SPHINXBUILD% -M help %SOURCEDIR% %BUILDDIR% %SPHINXOPTS% %O%

:end
popd
```

EDIT: Added makefile used to build the rst's

Comment: Can you intercept the .tex file?

Comment: The problem looks as if the document is only compiled on time. However the `tikz-hf` package is based on tikzmarks and thus needs to be compiled two times

Comment: How do you build the pdf from your source? Do you have any kind of makefile like https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/6a802a4a8bd3b652a91e4effd5e3a7efe2df35bd/sphinx/texinputs/Makefile?at=default#cl-57 where you could increase the number of latex runs to at least 2?

Comment: I use the standard makefile that `python-sphinx` creates -- added it to the question. Also, building the PDF works file -- it's only when I am building the HTML that it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found why this was happening: the problem was in the [`sphinx.ext.imgmath`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/fe06eebfb5c2a24f8a0e297aef2e7a5ec82b062c/sphinx/ext/imgmath.py) extension + hf-tikz not working well with the DVI files.

When converting the math equations, sphinx creates a very basic latex document, and compiles it using `latexpdf` into a DVI file. After that the file is converted into an SVG, and the resulting svg file is copied to the sphinx's `_build` directory. The problem is that dvisvgm (used by `imgmath`) cannot convert tikz stuff. Alternative would be using extended DVI, but that doesn't work well either.

The solution is to compile everything into PDF, and convert that pdf into SVG. This is slightly problematic, and the only way I found is to use [pdf2svg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/pdf2svg.1.html) + [pdfcrop](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop?lang=en). I ended up modifying the `imgmath.py` into a custom extension. Below are the changes that I put in the `imgmath.py`. The changes require the use of external applications, so I don't think there is a merit in creating a pull request (at least not with a more scalable solution).

Changes in the `imgmath.py`:

1. Create a new method:

```py
def convert_pdf_to_svg(pdfpath, builder):
    # type: (str, Builder) -> Tuple[str, int]
    """Convert DVI file to SVG image."""
    tempdir = ensure_tempdir(builder)
    filename = path.join(tempdir, 'math.svg')

    name = 'pdfcrop'
    command = [name, pdfpath, pdfpath]
    run_external_command(command, name)

    name = 'pdf2svg'
    command = [name, pdfpath, filename]
    run_external_command(command, name)
    return filename, None
```

2. In the `compile_math` function, inside the `try` block, replace the return statement with the following

```py
if builder.config.imgmath_pdf2svg:
  return path.join(tempdir, 'math.pdf')
else:
  return path.join(tempdir, 'math.dvi')
```

3. Inside the `render_math` method, in the block titles `# .dvi -> .png/svg`, replace the `try` block with the following

```
try:
    if image_format == 'png':
        imgpath, depth = convert_dvi_to_png(dvipath, self.builder)
    elif image_format == 'svg':
        if self.builder.config.imgmath_pdf2svg:
            imgpath, depth = convert_pdf_to_svg(dvipath, self.builder)
        else:
            imgpath, depth = convert_dvi_to_svg(dvipath, self.builder)
except InvokeError:
    self.builder._imgmath_warned_image_translator = True  # type: ignore
    return None, None
```

4. Finally, add a new configuration entry in the very end of the `imgmath.py`:

```py
    app.add_config_value('imgmath_pdf2svg', False, 'html')
```

After that, you can write in the **conf.py** to enable the tikz images.

```py
imgmath_image_format = 'svg'
imgmath_latex = 'latexmk'
imgmath_latex_args = ['-pdf']
imgmath_pdf2svg = True  # Available only in the custom `imgmath.py`
```

**patch for [imgmath](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/fe06eebfb5c2a24f8a0e297aef2e7a5ec82b062c/sphinx/ext/imgmath.py) extension.** Includes some other stuff :)

The patch goes `a`->`b`.

```py
--- a/imgmath.py
+++ b/imgmath.py
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
 import sys
 import tempfile
 from hashlib import sha1
-from os import path
+from os import path, symlink
 from subprocess import CalledProcessError, PIPE
 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Tuple

@@ -157,6 +157,11 @@
     with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
         f.write(latex)

+    for add_file in builder.config.imgmath_latex_additional_files:
+        filename = path.join(tempdir, path.basename(add_file))
+        if not path.exists(filename):
+            symlink(path.join(builder.confdir, add_file), filename)
+
     # build latex command; old versions of latex don't have the
     # --output-directory option, so we have to manually chdir to the
     # temp dir to run it.
@@ -165,9 +170,15 @@
     command.extend(builder.config.imgmath_latex_args)
     command.append('math.tex')

+    output_extension = 'dvi'
+    if builder.config.imgmath_latex == 'xelatex':
+        output_extension = 'xdv'
+    if builder.config.imgmath_pdf2svg:
+        output_extension = 'pdf'
+
     try:
         subprocess.run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd=tempdir, check=True)
-        return path.join(tempdir, 'math.dvi')
+        return path.join(tempdir, 'math.' + output_extension)
     except OSError:
         logger.warning(__('LaTeX command %r cannot be run (needed for math '
                           'display), check the imgmath_latex setting'),
@@ -177,7 +188,7 @@
         raise MathExtError('latex exited with error', exc.stderr, exc.stdout)


-def convert_dvi_to_image(command: List[str], name: str) -> Tuple[bytes, bytes]:
+def run_external_command(command: List[str], name: str) -> Tuple[bytes, bytes]:
     """Convert DVI file to specific image format."""
     try:
         ret = subprocess.run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, check=True)
@@ -203,7 +214,7 @@
         command.append('--depth')
     command.append(dvipath)

-    stdout, stderr = convert_dvi_to_image(command, name)
+    stdout, stderr = run_external_command(command, name)

     depth = None
     if builder.config.imgmath_use_preview:
@@ -227,7 +238,7 @@
     command.extend(builder.config.imgmath_dvisvgm_args)
     command.append(dvipath)

-    stdout, stderr = convert_dvi_to_image(command, name)
+    stdout, stderr = run_external_command(command, name)

     depth = None
     if builder.config.imgmath_use_preview:
@@ -239,6 +250,21 @@
                 break

     return filename, depth
+
+def convert_pdf_to_svg(pdfpath, builder):
+    # type: (str, Builder) -> Tuple[str, int]
+    """Convert DVI file to SVG image."""
+    tempdir = ensure_tempdir(builder)
+    filename = path.join(tempdir, 'math.svg')
+
+    name = 'pdfcrop'
+    command = [name, pdfpath, pdfpath]
+    run_external_command(command, name)
+
+    name = 'pdf2svg'
+    command = [name, pdfpath, filename]
+    run_external_command(command, name)
+    return filename, None


 def render_math(self: HTMLTranslator, math: str) -> Tuple[str, int]:
@@ -291,7 +317,10 @@
         if image_format == 'png':
             imgpath, depth = convert_dvi_to_png(dvipath, self.builder)
         elif image_format == 'svg':
-            imgpath, depth = convert_dvi_to_svg(dvipath, self.builder)
+            if self.builder.config.imgmath_pdf2svg:
+                imgpath, depth = convert_pdf_to_svg(dvipath, self.builder)
+            else:
+                imgpath, depth = convert_dvi_to_svg(dvipath, self.builder)
     except InvokeError:
         self.builder._imgmath_warned_image_translator = True  # type: ignore
         return None, None
@@ -396,8 +425,10 @@
                          ['-gamma', '1.5', '-D', '110', '-bg', 'Transparent'],
                          'html')
     app.add_config_value('imgmath_dvisvgm_args', ['--no-fonts'], 'html')
+    app.add_config_value('imgmath_pdf2svg', False, 'html')
     app.add_config_value('imgmath_latex_args', [], 'html')
     app.add_config_value('imgmath_latex_preamble', '', 'html')
+    app.add_config_value('imgmath_latex_additional_files', [], 'html')
     app.add_config_value('imgmath_add_tooltips', True, 'html')
     app.add_config_value('imgmath_font_size', 12, 'html')
     app.connect('build-finished', cleanup_tempdir)
```

Comment: You probably used an outdated version of dvisvgm. The recent ones convert your hf-tikz example without problems.